# What is the block / confirmation time for NXT coin?

Tags: block, nxt

what is the block time to get my transaction confirmation? Do i still have to wait 10+ minutes to make sure a double spend didnt happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions are being included into blocks in 1 minute in average. Longer you wait - higher a chance that a double-spending won't happen. There is no such a number that guarantees 100% irreversibility.

1 confirmation is not secure at all. 10 confirmations is recommended for small amounts, 720 confirmations - for big ones.

Comment: i just sent 8 nxt to one of my wallets and its been 5-10 minutes and i still didn't get any confirmations yet. but it does show up that its sent in the other wallet.

Comment: 1 minute is AVERAGE time, real time varies from seconds to an hour. Also it can be a local node issue related to incorrect time/timezone, bad connection or a client software bug.